# Google Maps clear/reload markers with one bug

Tags: xml, api, maps, markers

ALCON
I'm SOO close to my first Webpage build.  Its been lots of fun but pulling my hair out on this last bug.  So.... 

My webpage displays a google map with markers.  The marker locations are pulled from an .xml file that changes every few minutes.  I wanted to update the map when the xml file change but I couldn't figure that out.  So I'm having the page clear the markers and reload every 5 seconds.  Everything works correct EXCEPT the xml read function.  But I know the read code works because I have a copy of the code in the InitMAP function.  And I know the triggerDownload is being called because the markers clear and the computer beeps every 5 sec..

Open webpage - works
Load Map - works
Load markers (by code in the InitMap function) - works
5 seconds later, markers clear (clearOverlays function inside triggerDownload function) - works
markers never reappear (remainder of triggerDownload function.
Beeps every 5 sec so the setInterval function is working...

So my question is: what an I missing in the TriggerDownload function?  Why don't the markers appear when I call triggerDownload when its IDENTICAL code to the code in the InitMap function.

```js
< script type = "text/javascript" >


  var customLabel = {
    restaurant: {
      label: 'ROBERT'
    },
    bar: {
      label: 'BOB'
    }
  };



var map, infoWindow, intervalId;
var markersArray = [];


var customIcons = {
  restaurant: {
    icon: 'http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/ridefinder-images/mm_20_blue.png'
  },
  bar: {
    icon: 'http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/ridefinder-images/mm_20_red.png'
  }
};




function clearOverlays() {
  for (var i = 0; i < markersArray.length; i++) {
    markersArray[i].setMap(null);
  }
}

function downloadUrl(url, callback) {
  var request = window.ActiveXObject ? new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP') : new XMLHttpRequest;

  request.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (request.readyState == 4) {
      request.onreadystatechange = doNothing;
      callback(request, request.status);
    }
  };

  request.open('GET', url, true);
  request.send(null);
}





function initMap() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(-33.863276, 151.207977),
    zoom: 12
  });

  var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;

  // Trigger downloadUrl at an interval
  intervalId = setInterval(triggerDownload, 5000); //need to add for 5 sec delay


  // /* **************** This section will be removed when triggerDownload works**************************
  downloadUrl('/TXSG/data.xml', function(data) {
    var xml = data.responseXML;
    var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");

    for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {

      var id = markers[i].getAttribute('id');
      var name = markers[i].getAttribute('name');
      var address = markers[i].getAttribute('address');
      var type = markers[i].getAttribute('type');
      var point = new google.maps.LatLng(
        parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute('lat')),
        parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute('lng')));

      var html = "<b>" + name + "</b> <br/>" + address + "<br/>" + point;
      var icon = customLabel[type] || {};

      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        position: point,
        label: icon.label
        //                icon: icon.icon
      }); //google.maps

      markersArray.push(marker);
      bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html);
    } //for loop

  }); //downloadUrl

  // *************************************************************************************** */
}




function bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html) {
  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
    infoWindow.setContent(html);
    infoWindow.open(map, marker);
  });
}



function triggerDownload() {
  clearOverlays(); //works up to here....


  downloadUrl('/TXSG/data2.xml', function(data) {
    var xml = data.responseXML;
    var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");

    for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {

      var id = markers[i].getAttribute('id');
      var name = markers[i].getAttribute('name');
      var address = markers[i].getAttribute('address');
      var type = markers[i].getAttribute('type');
      var point = new google.maps.LatLng(
        parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute('lat')),
        parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute('lng')));

      var html = "<b>" + name + "</b> <br/>" + address + "<br/>" + point;
      var icon = customLabel[type] || {};

      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        position: point,
        label: icon.label
        //                icon: icon.icon
      }); //google.maps

      markersArray.push(marker);
      bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html);
    } //for loop

    beep();

  }); //downloadUrl

} //function




function doNothing() {}

<
/script>
```

And yes, I'm reading to different .xml files.  Just to see when the data changes for debugging....

Comment: At the end of `function clearOverlays()`, add `markersArray=[];` to initialize the array.